# regex match all in quote but not when line start with slashes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Regex in PHP with preg_replace().
Match all in quote but not when line start with slashes

source code:

```
// eehen nhdhdhd ooe "jjejej" ejeje "keihjen" jehhemm
jejej "jejeooe" kekek "jilnana" jennbeb
```

needed result:

```
// eehen nhdhdhd ooe "jjejej" ejeje "keihjen" jehhemm
jejej <span class="red">"jejeooe"</span> kekek <span class="red">"jilnana"</span> jennbeb
```

My regex match only the last in quote. I will replace all in quote including quote with an outer Span, but not all in quote in a comment line.

my regex:

```
'/^((?!\/\/).*)(".*")/m'
```

my replace:

```
'$1<span class="red">$2</span>'
```

my result:

```
// eehen nhdhdhd ooe "jjejej" ejeje "keihjen" jehhemm
jejej "jejeooe" kekek <span class="red">"jilnana"</span> jennbeb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchor makes it so your search starts at the beginning of the string then proceeds. I would just skip any lines starting with `//`s by using PCRE verbs.

```
^\/\/.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|("[^"]+")
```

then you can just replace with

```
<span class="red">$1</span>
```

https://regex101.com/r/bLkctu/1/

For entityized values:

```
^\/\/.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(&quot;.*?&quot;)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bLkctu/2/

Comment: works nice. SKIP and FAIL was new for me. but i have forgotten a detail. first i make a htmlentities(), than i have not `"` but `&quot;`. i have tested your regex with `&quot;` but don't work. please can you replace the `"` with `&quot;` for me in your regex?